# Rails 3.2 upgrade fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error after I upgraded to `Rails v3.2`. I have been running 3.2.0.rc2 before and it was working fine.

```
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/kapil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/specifications/actionmailer-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x00000108a21eb8> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/kapil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/specifications/actionpack-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x00000108995dc8> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/kapil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/specifications/activemodel-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x00000108a64858> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/kapil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/specifications/activerecord-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x00000108840a68> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/kapil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/specifications/activeresource-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x000001089b2658> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/kapil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/specifications/rails-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x000001073d4fe8> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/kapil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/specifications/railties-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x00000108913dc8> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/kapil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/specifications/actionmailer-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x00000108a21eb8> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/kapil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/specifications/actionpack-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x00000108995dc8> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/kapil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/specifications/activemodel-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x00000108a64858> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/kapil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/specifications/activerecord-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x00000108840a68> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/kapil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/specifications/activeresource-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x000001089b2658> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/kapil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/specifications/rails-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x000001073d4fe8> 3.2.0"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/kapil/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/specifications/railties-3.2.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x00000108913dc8> 3.2.0"]
```

Comment: What version of ruby gems are you using? gem --version

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure if this is related, but if you're running Ruby 1.8.7, you need to update RubyGems to 1.8.15. Update with `gem update --system`

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/20/rails-3-2-0-faster-dev-mode-routing-explain-queries-tagged-logger-store

Answer (score 0):

what version of rubygems are you using?

It looks like there's an issue with versions 1.8.13 and before with rails 3.2 https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4317

Try updating rubygems to 1.8.14

Comment: i have gem -v => 1.5.0, let me try and upgrade